# Determine if a tibble is grouped or not

Tags: r, dplyr

Is there a function to determine if a tibble is a grouped one or not.

I use the following code to create an aggregated variable without shrinking the dataset:

```
mydataset %>% select(count, group) %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  mutate(count_group = sum(count))
```

If I use mutate, I have a grouped tibble. If I use summarise, I have a simple tibble.

Is there a function, like `as.grouped()` which allows to determine the character grouped of a tibble?

Comment: Are you looking for `is.grouped_df` in `dplyr`?

Comment: Yes, thanks. It does not appear in the index of the help of the dplyr package.

Comment: @YCR - If you use the pacman package then `p_funs(dplyr)` would have shown you `is.grouped_df`

Comment: `apropos('grouped')`

Comment: @Dason p_funs is not very practical, the index of the package is better. (but incomplete, apparently)

Comment: What do you mean it's not very practical? I use it quite a bit.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The functions `is.grouped_df()` and `is_grouped_df()` will both return a TRUE logical if it's a grouped tibble, and FALSE if it is not.

```
# Create a tibble    
df <- tibble(x = c(5, 2, NA))
# Group by column 'x'
gdf <- group_by(df, x)
# Returns FALSE
is.grouped_df(df)
# Returns TRUE
is.grouped_df(gdf)
```

Answer (score 4):

of course you are aware that you can use `ungroup()` to remove any grouping. Anyway, there is pretty way to figure out if the dataframe is grouped, and this is simply by printing the dataframe. The grouping variables will appear on top.

```
dataframe <- data_frame('group' = c('a','a','b'),
                        'value' = c(1,2,3))

dataframe %>% group_by(group)

Source: local data frame [3 x 2]
**Groups: group [2]**

  group value
  <chr> <dbl>
1     a     1
2     a     2
3     b     3
```

Answer (score 3):

Information on grouping is saved as an [attribute](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/attributes.html). Example:

```
library("tidyverse")
a <- mtcars %>% group_by(cyl)
attributes(a)
$names
 [1] "mpg"  "cyl"  "disp" "hp"   "drat" "wt"   "qsec" "vs"   "am"   "gear"
[11] "carb"

$row.names
 [1] "Mazda RX4"           "Mazda RX4 Wag"       "Datsun 710"
 [4] "Hornet 4 Drive"      "Hornet Sportabout"   "Valiant"
 [7] "Duster 360"          "Merc 240D"           "Merc 230"
[10] "Merc 280"            "Merc 280C"           "Merc 450SE"
[13] "Merc 450SL"          "Merc 450SLC"         "Cadillac Fleetwood"
[16] "Lincoln Continental" "Chrysler Imperial"   "Fiat 128"
[19] "Honda Civic"         "Toyota Corolla"      "Toyota Corona"
[22] "Dodge Challenger"    "AMC Javelin"         "Camaro Z28"
[25] "Pontiac Firebird"    "Fiat X1-9"           "Porsche 914-2"
[28] "Lotus Europa"        "Ford Pantera L"      "Ferrari Dino"
[31] "Maserati Bora"       "Volvo 142E"

$class
[1] "grouped_df" "tbl_df"     "tbl"        "data.frame"

$groups
# A tibble: 3 x 2
    cyl .rows
  <dbl> <list>
1     4 <int [11]>
2     6 <int [7]>
3     8 <int [14]>
```

`attributes` function can be used to check for the presence of grouping attribute:

```
any(names(attributes(a)) == "groups")
```